# Obter o menor valor com o map em um dict

Tags: python, lista, dicionário, map

Estou estudando a função `map()` e queria saber se tem como eu recuperar o menor valor de um dicionário dentro de uma lista. Da forma que estou fazendo só estou conseguindo alterar todos os valores.

```
arroz = [
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 20.15, 'mercado': 'mercado_1'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 19.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_2'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 22.00, 'mercado': 'mercado_3'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_4'}]


def menorpreco(arroz, valor):
    def item(p):
        p['preco'] = valor
        return p
    return map(item, arroz)


print(list(menorpreco(arroz, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `item` está modificando o valor do preço porque você faz `p['preco'] = valor`, então não parece ser o que você precisa.

Além disso, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) serve para aplicar uma função a todos os elementos de um iterável, retornando os resultados desta função (no caso, ela está usando a função `item`, que modifica os preços, por isso o retorno tem os preços modificados).

Se você quer buscar o menor preço, use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
def menorpreco(arroz):
    return min(arroz, key=lambda d : d['preco'])

arroz = [
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 20.15, 'mercado': 'mercado_1'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 19.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_2'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 22.00, 'mercado': 'mercado_3'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_4'}]

mais_barato = menorpreco(arroz)
print(mais_barato) # {'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_4'}
```

O parâmetro `key` indica qual valor será usado na comparação, e no caso eu usei o preço.

O retorno é todo o dicionário que contém o menor preço. Mas se quiser apenas o valor, basta fazer `mais_barato['preco']`.

---

Mas em caso de empate (tem mais de um item que é o mais barato), você pode retornar uma lista com os itens mais baratos:

```
def menorpreco(arroz):
    # primeiro vê qual o menor preço
    menor_preco = min(arroz, key=lambda d : d['preco'])['preco']
    # retorna uma lista com todos os itens cujo preço é igual ao menor_preco
    return [ item for item in arroz if item['preco'] == menor_preco]

arroz = [
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 20.15, 'mercado': 'mercado_1'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_5'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 19.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_2'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 22.00, 'mercado': 'mercado_3'},
{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_4'}]

print(menorpreco(arroz)) # [{'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_5'}, {'item': 'arroz', 'preco': 17.99, 'mercado': 'mercado_4'}]
```

Comment: Obrigado. me ajudou e muito no entendimento. vlw